# Emacs pdf-tools writing function

Tags: functions, pdf, pdf-tools

Recently I am indulging in Emacs. I tried to use it as my LaTeX tool, so I installed pdf-tools. If I add

```
(pdf-tools-install)
```

in my init file, it will take about 2 seconds to start Emacs. So I want to write a function such that "pdf-tools-install" will run after I open a pdf file. But "add-hook" only works when a major mode is recognized, and we can recognize pdf only after pdf-tools is installed. I think it may relate to regex, but I don't know much about it. Could you help me with this function? Thanks!

Comment: Try `(add-hook 'doc-view-mode-hook #'pdf-tools-install)`

Comment: @politza Sadly it does not work, pdf file is still recognized as Fundamental mode.

Comment: I suggest either install pdf tools in an idle timer, or autoload it and use an eval-after-load. Or both. (Sorry for not providing code I'm on a mobile device)

Comment: When I hit `C-c C-c` in my documents it switches between pdfview and Docview so you could see if pdf-tools is initialize when the pdf is opened after applying politza answer.

Comment: @Manan Mehta But it should be in `doc-view-mode`.

Comment: Do you need to install it every time you start Emacs? I thought the installation is only needed once and you can use it immediately ever after. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work! Thanks guys!

I added

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.pdf\\'" . doc-view-mode))
```

and

```
(add-hook 'doc-view-mode-hook #'pdf-tools-install)
```